# How do I wait for a service/process to start before continuing a batch script?

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-services, batch-file, wait

I am writing a windows batch script to uninstall some software. However I need to wait after the uninstaller has finished for a service to be restarted before continuing with the next uninstall.

I can make the script wait for the uninstaller to finsh using:-

> `for /f "usebackq" %%M in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process_1%"') do if not %%M==%ignore_result% goto 1`

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the script to then wait for a service to start before continuing the script and running more uninstalls.

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: You can use `sc query <servicename>` to get out the status of a service, if you can then figure out a way of reading that output in your batchfile you should be ok.

Comment: Does it have to be a batch file?  Seems like it would be a lot easier with VBScript.

Comment: My programming skills are minimal so am using a very high level language to program in. However, I am open to doing this another way, as I can always call a VBScript from within a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

What about this to avoid using an intermediate file

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,4" %%A IN (`sc query AcquisitionService`) DO (
    IF %%A==STATE SET serviceStatus=%%B
)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK from comments I have used the script below to sort out the problem. I was hoping not to use a intermediate file, but when needs must....

`@echo off

if exist service.txt del service.txt

set process=setup.exe

set ignore_result=INFO:

:1

for /f "usebackq" %%M in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process%"') do if not %%M==%ignore_result% goto 1

:2

sc query AcquisitionService>service.txt

find "RUNNING"<service.txt>nul

if errorlevel 1 goto 2

:3

echo.

echo Stuff finished.......`

Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The anwser provided by the poster works but it uses a temporary file.
I found a way to avoid that using the pipe separator.

This code will start the service then wait until it has started :

```
sc start ServiceName
:1
sc query ServiceName>NUL | find "RUNNING">NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto 1
(...)
```

The rediection (>NUL) are optional, or at least they don't make a difference in my case.

Comment: It doesn't work for me with (>NUL) redirections, works great when I removed it.